# Display and get the result of a QMessageBox from outside of a QObject

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to display and get the result a message box from outside of a QObject class. I seem to be able to generate the dialog like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <QApplication>
#include <QtConcurrentRun>
#include <QMessageBox>

class DialogHandler : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

signals:
  void MySignal();

public:
  DialogHandler()
  {
    connect( this, SIGNAL( MySignal() ), this, SLOT(MySlot()) );
  }

  void EmitSignal()
  {
    emit MySignal();
  }

public slots:
  void MySlot()
  {
    QMessageBox* dialog = new QMessageBox;
    dialog->setText("Test Text");
    dialog->exec();
    int result = dialog->result();
    if(result)
    {
      std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "invalid" << std::endl;
    }
  }
};

#include "main.moc" // For CMake's automoc

void MyFunction(DialogHandler* dialogHandler)
{
  dialogHandler->EmitSignal();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  DialogHandler* dialogHandler = new DialogHandler;

  MyFunction(dialogHandler);

  return app.exec();
}
```

To get the result back in MyFunction, it seems to work to do simply pass an object to fill with the result like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <QApplication>
#include <QtConcurrentRun>
#include <QMessageBox>

class DialogHandler : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

signals:
  void MySignal(int* returnValue);

public:
  DialogHandler()
  {
    connect( this, SIGNAL( MySignal(int*) ), this, SLOT(MySlot(int*)), Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection );
  }

  void EmitSignal(int* returnValue)
  {
    emit MySignal(returnValue);
  }

public slots:
  void MySlot(int* returnValue)
  {
    std::cout << "input: " << *returnValue << std::endl;
    QMessageBox* dialog = new QMessageBox;
    dialog->addButton(QMessageBox::Yes);
    dialog->addButton(QMessageBox::No);
    dialog->setText("Test Text");
    dialog->exec();
    int result = dialog->result();
    if(result == QMessageBox::Yes)
    {
      *returnValue = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      *returnValue = 0;
    }
  }
};

#include "main.moc" // For CMake's automoc

void MyFunction(DialogHandler* dialogHandler)
{
  int returnValue = -1;
  dialogHandler->EmitSignal(&returnValue);

  std::cout << "returnValue: " << returnValue << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  DialogHandler* dialogHandler = new DialogHandler;

  QtConcurrent::run(MyFunction, dialogHandler);

  std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
  return app.exec();
}
```

Does that seem reasonable? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: So you're using multiple threads? You could create a QObject-derived class in MyClass doing nothing else than showing the msgbox in a slot, or you could connect the object in the other thread to your widget and show the messagebox there.

Comment: Ah, right, I was attributing it to not being in a QObject class, but you are clearly correct that it is because that class is not in the same thread. I still don't know how to connect the signal and slot though because I am here:

Form::MyClass::MyFunction()
{
 ... doing the function ...
 ... an error happens ...
 ProduceMessageBox()
}

Since MyClass is not a QObject, it cannot emit signals, so how do I make it call a function of Form?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible quite like you have it, but with a bit of work it could be done.  One option, of course, would be to convert your class to a QObject, at which point you could send signals.  It doesn't help for the delay during exec, however.  If that is necessary, you could have a messaging class that lives in the main UI thread, but can be called from other threads.  The function called from other threads would need to lock, make a semaphore, and send an event to itself with the semaphore and message to be displayed.  Then, in customEvent (which would be in the UI thread), you would create the message box, exec it, and trigger the semaphore after the message box is cleared.

Of course, things get a bit more complicated if you need to send information back the other way as well.  Then you'll need a complete subsystem for your program, instead of just one basic class like I describe here.

Comment: I think I got the "one way" case (see my edit in the Question). Is that what you meant? It doesn't do any explicit locking, but it seems to work? Do you happen to have an example of how to send information back?

Comment: I didn't completely validate your code, but the approach could work.  You need to be sure your DialogHandler is instantiated in the UI thread (as you've done in the example main).  Sending information back could be done via a custom event back to the originating object, though I don't have any particular examples handy.

Comment: I thought this was working, but it only seems to work the first time through a loop, and then the program just seems to stall (processor is at 0%, but it never runs the second iteration)? http://codepad.org/KoyJBU6C - Here I would expect the message box to be shown 3 times in succession. However, it is only shown once, then it does this "stall" that I mentioned. Any thoughts on why that might happen?

Comment: Nevermind, it was an unrelated thing - I had to set QApplication::quitOnLastWindowClosed() to false so the application didn't quit after the window was closed (though it didn't seem to quit all the way..., but that fixes it).